# Add source file path comments to webpack bundle

Tags: javascript, webpack

My current webpack configuration produces a bundle, where each part is prepended with a comment like this

```
/* 0 */
/***/ function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {
}
```

I would like to add a source JS file path for each function for easier navigation. Eg.

```
/* 0  path/to/source/file.js */
/***/ function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {
}
```

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 3):

Ok found an answer after a bit of reading the official docs. Setting output.pathinfo to true in the webpack config file does exactly that.